# tcolorbox stamp look

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox` and was wondering if there is a library or similar to get a "stamp like" feeling (i.e. more or less random color-differences/pressure points/clear spots/...)

That looks a bit like what I'm searching for
https://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Free-Round-Stamp-Mockup-PSD-F.jpg

I'm sure there is something, I may just dont know what to look for exactly.
Can someone help please?

Comment: `tcolorbox` option `overlay` (or `underlay`), accompanied with a stamp-like image, may help.

Answer (score 2):

From section `10.3 Watermark Option Keys` of the [tcolorbox manual](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), there is a few options to insert watermarks on your tcolorboxes.

The following MWE presents an example with text and another with an image. You may change opacity and also check the manual for overlay and underlay options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  colback=red!5!white,
  every box/.style={enhanced,
    before=\par\smallskip, after=\par\smallskip},
  every box on layer 2/.style={reset,every box,colback=yellow!10!white,
    drop fuzzy shadow},
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  watermark opacity=0.4
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={My title}, watermark text={\color{blue}My Watermark Text}, watermark opacity=0.4]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[watermark graphics={example-image-a}]
  \lipsum[66]
  \tcblower
  \lipsum[66]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]